# Is it an antipattern to rely on Context.Provider existence higher in components tree in React?

Tags: reactjs

Consider following component:

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import FormContext from "../FormContext";

const Input = ({ name }) => {
  const getInputValue = useContext(FormContext);
  return <input name={name} value={getInputValue(name)} />;
}
```

Is relying on fact that `typeof getInputValue === "function"` and not checking it is being considered as an anti-pattern? As it restricts places of usage of this component to places where FormContext is defined somewhere up in components tree.

I have seen some articles and discussions about this, but unable to find them now.
[Official doc](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) does not cover this  case.

However [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5299d372a220584e75a031c13b3d555607af13f8/types/react/index.d.ts#L833) of `useContext` do not assume that `undefined` may be returned from `useContext` if Context would not be found higher in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is more of an existencial question than anything. How do you know if a variable you imported from another file is a function or not? It's your application and you are the best person to access if you can assume what is what.

On your direct question: **No, it is not an anti-pattern.**

Comment: Let's suppose that's a component in some components library that is used by a few projects, in this case I restrict developers working on these projects. And they can not directly change my component and may not know how it's implemented. Things get more complicated in this case.

Comment: To me the only anti-pattern here is using `useContext` while not setting up the `ContextProvider` before. That is an anti-pattern because `context` expects the user to set the provider, that is the way it works.

What you can do is create a custom hook that checks if everything is there. You can use `useContext` inside a hook. [Custom Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

Comment: whats prevents form the child component to access and alter FormContext fields and by that break the unidirectional principle?  It is just a mask over a global variable under that node in the DOM tree..